# Pass data from child to parent with a computed property in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, filter, nuxt.js

I want to make a search component that receives an object and then filters it by user input. Then pass it again to parent to show what i filtered. (Nuxt)

```js
// Parent component
<AppSearch  :bookmarks="bookmarks" />

...

bookmarks = [ { "title": "Facebook", "url": "https://facebook.com" }, { "title": "Google", "url": "https://google.com/" } ]
```

```js
// Child search component
<template>
      <input type="text" v-model="searchQuery"> </input>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
      props: ['bookmarks'],
        data() {
            return {
              searchQuery: null,
            }
        },
          computed: {
            filteringBookmarks:{
              get: function() {
              if(this.searchQuery){
                return this.bookmarks.filter(data => data.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()))
              } else{
                return this.bookmarks;
              }
              }
            }
          },
        watch: {
        filteringBookmarks(newValue) {
            console.log(`yes, computed property changed: ${newValue}`); // <--- INFINITES MESSAGES
            this.$emit('update:bookmarks',  filteringBookmarks)
        }
    },
    }
</script>
```

I've tried another ways but always ends in the same spot, whole website freezing. Its seems like never stop refreshing "bookmarks". Maybe is a circular problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to avoid this circular issue is to watch the `searchQuery`

```html
<script>
    export default {
      props: ['bookmarks'],
        data() {
            return {
              searchQuery: null,
            }
        },
        watch: {
        searchQuery(newValue) {
          let filteringBookmarks=[]
         if(newValue){
           filteringBookmarks=this.bookmarks.filter(data => data.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()))
         }else{
           filteringBookmarks=this.bookmarks;
         }

          this.$emit('update:bookmarks',  filteringBookmarks)
        }
    },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This solved my problem partially, as i had to add an event listener (because that emit doesn't work for me) and i had to create a duplicate of 'bookmarks', because when i was changing it, it was changed in the child too, and we dont want that. So i just pass 'bookmarks' to child, and in the parent i use 'filteredBookmarks' which is the changing one and has the initial value of 'bookmarks'. I hope that those who come here understand this.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are emitting a computed value to the parent component, and the parent updates the bookmarks and pass it as a prop to the child component which makes the computed  property to be updated and since you have a watcher on the computed property, it will again emits it's new value causing an **infinite loop**.

A **solution** can be to emit search query itself and then filter the results on the parent element.